# Robocopy last modified: more accurate than a day?

Tags: date, batch-file, robocopy

I'm working on a Windows batch file to perform a two-way sync with a server. The batch file will be used by multiple people to syncronize several computers with a single network location. Due to restrictions I won't get into, it HAS to be a batch file. No vbscript, no javascript, only windows batch. Powershell commands may be okay as long as I can run them from inside the batch file.

In order to allow file deletions, it runs robocopy several times. First, it copies files newer than the last time the script was ran using the /MAXLAD switch. It does this in both directions. Then, it does a mirror with the /l switch and checks the exit code to detect extra files. If either side has extra files, it runs the mirror for real, in the appropriate direction.

The script works well as-is, but...

The problem is, /MAXLAD accepts a date in the form YYYYMMDD, so if you create a file locally, run the sync script, then immediately delete the file and sync again, it comes back from the grave. In order to successfully delete a file it needs to have been unmodified for a least a day prior to the last time you ran the script. I would like some way of removing this restriction, so it can be ran as often as my users please and work as expected.

My question is this: Is there some way to be more precise with the last access time? Even if I could narrow it to the hour, it'd be an improvement. Should I be doing something other than robocopy to copy the new files?

Answer (score 1):

Using `ROBOCOPY` AFAIK, it is not possible to get accuracy any more granular than one day.
However, it **IS** possible to get more granular using two other methods.

```
DIR /o:d /a:-d
```

will sort the files of the current directory from newest to oldest, and leaving any directories out of the list.
To reverse the listing so it's oldest to newest, change `/o:d` to `/o:-d`.

---

Also, the `FOR` statement can do the same sort of thing.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set count=0
:: If some other process left %tmp%\temp.txt, delete it.
if exist %tmp%\temp.txt del %tmp%\temp.txt

for %%x in (*.*) do (
    set /a count=!count!+1
    :: Capture Size
    set size=000000%%~zx
    :: Capture Date and Time
    set td=%%~tx
    :: Turn Date into YYYY/MM/DD format
    set dd=!td:~6,4!/!td:~0,5!
    :: Set tt=hour of day
    set tt=!td:~11,2!
    :: Turn AM/PM time into 24 hour day time
    if !td:~-2!==PM set /a tt=!tt!+12
    :: Add :Minutes to time
    set tt=!tt!:!td:~-5,2!
    :: Append Size Date Time FileName to temp.txt
    call echo !size:~-5! !dd! !tt! %%x>>%tmp%\temp.txt
rem    :: Create variable size[n] and set it to: Size Date Time FileName
rem    call set size[!count!]=!size:~-5! !dd! !tt! %%x
)

echo.
echo Size  Date       Time  FileName
echo ===== ========== ===== ===============

::
:: Alternate 1: Replacing the Append line to `temp.
:: :: Print Array into %tmp%\temp.txt
:: for /l %%x in (1 1 %count%) do (
::  :: Pipe variable into a file
::  echo !size[%%x]!>>%tmp%\temp.txt
:: )

::
:: Alternate 2: Another way to iterate through the array size[n]
:: :loop
::   set /a ctr=%ctr%+1
::   echo !size[%ctr%]!
:: if %ctr% lss %count% goto loop

::
:: Sort temp.txt, starting at the 6th character (the date).
type %tmp%\temp.txt | sort.exe /+6
del %tmp%\temp.txt
echo.
```

The above code is not as long and complicated as it appears. Much of it is simply remarks, and nearly half takes up the code. Much of the rest is redundant code, shown just to display